# Help me understand this Latin "Dad Joke"

Tags: translation-explanation

The Paideia Institute's [In Medias Res magazine](https://medium.com/in-medias-res) recently published a compilation of [“Thirteen Dad Jokes from Ancient Rome.”](https://medium.com/in-medias-res/thirteen-dad-jokes-from-ancient-rome-for-fathers-day-850a1f1b9db2) Dad jokes are apparently supposed to be particularly cheesy jokes and puns ([the lowest form of humour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/the-lowest-form-of-humor)).

The jokes are presented in English, with weblinks to the original Latin, but no explanation how the joke works in Latin. Some of them work just as well in English; some are nigh untranslatable, and the translator veers quite far from the original to allow for wordplay in English.

Here is how one joke from Cicero's [*De oratore*, 2,249](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Cic.%20de%20Orat.%202.249&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0120), is translated:

> Philippus told a smelly guy, “It seems you’ve … (*sniffing*) … goat me surrounded!”

The original is:

> in male olentem "video me a te circumveniri" subridicule Philippus

I don't get it. Yes, he tells the smelly person, “I see you've got me surrounded,” that is pretty straightforward. Where is the pun in Latin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a footnote to his 1891 translation of the relevant sentence ([page 294](https://archive.org/details/oratoryandorato00ciceuoft/page/294/mode/2up)), J. S. Watson says this:

> 2 *Video me a te circumveniri.* Toup, in his Appendix to Theocritus, suggests that we should read *Video me a te non circum, sed hircumveniri*, referring to a similar joke of Aristophanes, *Acharn.* 850.

(Out of haste, I originally misinterpreted the footnote as saying that Toup suggested that *hircumveniri* was later falsely corrected to/replaced with *circumveniri*; but I now see that he actually thought that the full line is *Video me a te non circum* [= *circumveniri*]*, sed hircumveniri*.)

It's a good suggestion, I think, since billy-goats are identified with human body odor elsewhere in Latin literature – e.g., Catullus 71 and Horace, Epode 12. There's probably something in Plautus too, maybe Martial.

I don't know how widely accepted Toup's suggestion is. At any rate, it appears that the translator of the passage in your article was aware of it and followed it.

Comment: I like the suggestion of *hircumveniri* – as you’ve pointed out, *hircus* is routinely used to denote a bad smell (usually emanating from armpits!) (e.g. Plautus, *Pseudolus*, 735; and *Poenulus*, 870). However, in the Cicero passage in question he continues, “*At utrumque genus continet verbi ad litteram immutati similitudo*” which I understand to be saying that these sorts of pun contain a likeness to a word which is unchanged to the letter. If so, there’s no missing line. Perhaps the joke depends, therefore, on a certain pronunciation? Perhaps the ‘c’ is more of a ‘ch’ as in ‘loch’?

Comment: @Penelope, OLD lists both an adjective immutatus where the im- is a negating prefix ('without alteration, unchanged') and a verb immutare, where it's an intensifier ('to make different, alter, modify'). In his translation, Watson is taking it as the latter: 'yet it is the resemblance of words, with the change only of a letter, that constitutes both jokes.' Still, I did wonder the same thing as you, thinking particularly of Catullus 84, where commoda is pronounced chommoda and insidias hinsidias.

Comment: (Continued) However, I think the joke is weaker that way (though of course this is entirely subjective), because it relies on two bases: mispronunciation through aspiration and then a double interpretation of the resulting word, one of which would involve a punning word that P. possibly made up for the occasion. (I'll note in passing that I also think that Toup's addition of 'non circum sed' also makes for a weaker joke than simply 'Video me a te hircumveniri.')

Comment: @cnread “a punning word that P. possibly made up for the occasion” – hoc veri mehercule simile mihi videtur.